# Sentence starting with ''Verb'': "Attached please find…"

Tags: grammar

I, sometimes, receive mails from few suppliers to my company which include the below sentence in the mail body.

> Attached please find the xxx analysis.

Is this a correct sentence? If wrong, what will be the appropriate sentence?

Comment: We can tell that "attached" does not modify "document" by comparing it with, say, "In the garage please find the tools". I don't think you'd be tempted to say that the noun phrase is "in the garage tools"; that would be quite wrong. The preposition phrase "in the garage" is just like "attached", i.e.an adjunct of place that tells you where you will find the tools.

Comment: *Attached* in that sentence is not a verb; it's an adjective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's correct. The adjective (**Attached**) is placed far away from the noun that it modifies (**analysis**).* One could also word it like this (with or without the comma):

> Please find the xxx analysis, attached.

This means the same as "Please find the xxx analysis, **which is attached**."

Putting the word **attached** first is [conventional](https://www.google.com/search?q="attached+please+find") for indicating an attachment in a letter. "Attached please find" (with no comma) is a set phrase in this context.

* <sub>You could also understand "attached" as a name for where to find the attachment, i.e. as a modifier for "find", analogous to adverbs like "here". It doesn't make any difference because the meaning is the same.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The word **attached** is a past participle of the verb **attach**. One way of using a past participle is to make a [participial clause](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org.cn/intermediate-grammar/participle-clauses):

> Shouted at loudly, Peter walked home.
>   Peter walked home, shouted at loudly.

As you can see, the participial phrase can be placed at the beginning or end of the sentence, separated by a comma. You could therefore say:

> Attached, please find the xxx analysis
>   Please find the xxx analysis, attached.

It is, however, more common in this case the treat **find attached** as a phrasal verb: to use it in this way, you would write

> Please find attached the xxx analysis.
>   Please find the xxx analysis attached.

The first version is preferred if the description is quite long.

Comment: therefore, a comma is need after the word ''attached''?

Answer (score 0):

> *Attached please find the xxx analysis.*

It’s not wrong.

"Attached" is a preposed element. It doesn't modify "xxx analysis", but is integrated into the structure of the clause containing it, where it functions as an adjunct – an adjunct of place – for it tells you where you will find "the xxx analysis".